# Can I use regex or wild char on d.getVar [Yocto]

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am looking to get values of all the variables starting with some name. For my current solution, I parse the d and look for all the variables and pick out the ones starting with expected name.

But instead, can we use regex or wild char.

Something like this: d.getVar("ALLOWED_RECIPES_%")

Expect output: List of values for all variables starting with ALLOWED_RECIPE

Comment: How did you get all variables with `d`, so I can help more, I am thinking about something

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM Just simple looping. "for var in d:"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I tried to manage:

- **testvars.bb**

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

xVARIABLE1 = "1"
yVARIABLE2 = "2"
zVARIABLE3 = "3"
yVARIABLE4 = "4"
VARIABLEp5 = "5"
VARIABLEp6 = "6"

python do_getvars(){
    import re
    variables = list(filter(re.compile(".VARIABLE.").match, [i for i in d]))
    varvalues = {}
    for var in variables:
        varvalues[var] = d.getVar(var)
    bb.warn("Variables: %s" %varvalues)
}

addtask do_getvars
```

The example creates a regex for `.VARIABLE.`, and it checks for all matches on all `d` variables.

After that, it creates a dictionary for each variable and its value.

Output of `bitbake testvars -c getvars` :

```
WARNING: testvars-1.0-r0 do_getvars: Variables: {'zVARIABLE3': '3', 'yVARIABLE2': '2', 'yVARIABLE4': '4', 'xVARIABLE1': '1'}
```

**NOTE**:

Bitbake does not offer a way to get multiple variables together and for that the direct regex application is not possible with `d.getVar`, so a that is the best solution I can think of right now.